# Validate multi line commits angular style with validate-commit-msg

Tags: git, validation

I want to enforce angular commit style in one of my node JS repositories. The toolbelt that I'm using is:

- Husky for lifecycle hooks (pre-commit,pre-push,etc)
- Commitizen as a commit wizard along with cz-lerna-changelog

I tried using [validate-commit-msg](https://github.com/kentcdodds/validate-commit-msg) for commit validation angular style, but if I include a line break on my commit message the validation fails.  Here is an example commit:

```
fix(DB): fixed the bug 

affects: module-name

- Fixed SSL properties are now actual getters
- Added the missing modules (fs)
- Test coverage raised again to 100%
```

I tried configuring the tool using `"subjectPattern": "[.\n]+"` as an option, but it makes no difference.

I'm open to any other validation tool out there, so if you know something that will work I have no problem switching to it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Now I have found the actual problem, so I'm going to answer my own question.

What it is happening is that `validate-commit-msg` or `husky` (not sure which one decides which commit to validate) are validating **the previous commit**. So despite my current commit message is valid, it is failing because the previous one was not. This is specially problematic if you are trying to start using commit validation. Also it is unfair because commits will fail for the next committer, whose may be different from the one who made the bad commit.

There is an issue about this topic: https://github.com/conventional-changelog/validate-commit-msg/issues/85